# How to give Nintex Query List Action a dynamic CAML query

Tags: dynamic, user-defined-functions, caml, nintex-workflow

I am attempting to build a Nintex User Defined Action which will take a few variables and return a collection.  Users enter in the contents of a CAML query where clause into the variable CustomQuery.  I add CustomQuery to the CAML query portion of a Query list action as seen below.  My problem is that the CustomQuery seems to be ignored and all list items are returned.  How can I set up a Nintex Query list Action to utilize a dynamic CAML query?

### **User Defined Parameters**

[image: Picture]

- Collection = collection of list items found from query.
- CustomQuery = contents of Where CAML clause.
- Role = not important for this question.
- RolesListId = guid of list to query.
- RolesListUrl = url of list collection containing list to query.

### **Query List Action**

[image: Picture]